# Bitmap adapter retain thumbnails

Tags: android, bitmap, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-adapter

I have a recyclerview adapter that loads a low amount of photos (under 10) from memory and makes thumbnails of them, and each time I rotate the device it has to resize them again.

I know most adapters the activity or fragment takes care of hanging on to the backing data, but for this instance, is it possible to retain the thumbnails in the adapter, or what is the proper way to do that, such as like what an Image gallery would do on rotation with the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a 3rd party library like https://github.com/bumptech/glide or http://square.github.io/picasso/ and then make it cache the data whenever it's needed.

By using either Glide or Picasso I'd suggest you don't do anything to retain the `Fragment` or `Activity` instances as the image loading framework will take care of caching the bitmaps on disk or in memory - whatever you prefer.

Glide and Picasso works fine with local stored images as well.

Both imageloading frameworks are able to handle resizing of images (for thumbnails for instance).

You could probably make a caching mechanism on your own that could do the same as Glide or Picasso, but really, why try to re-invent the wheel? :-)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions and I totally understand the don't reinvent the wheel, but I don't need almost all the functionality of the libraries. I just want to know how you could keep a small set of images in the adapter, or at least a way to keep them and quickly give them back to the adapter.

Comment: @Stampede10343 if you're worried about the size of your app, you can run `ProGuard` on your release APK to minimise the size of the APK to a bare minimum. `ProGuard` can remove unused methods for instance.
You're asking for something that `Glide` or `Picasso` has out of the box: caching and it's a pretty big part of why they're so popular and widely used.
Also bear in mind that just 10 smaller sized images takes up quite a lot of memory if not kept correctly.

Comment: I am aware, but I simply cannot use external libraries.